How to merge 2 (or more) ggcuminc plots together (from cuminc function)?
Using R, I have two ggcuminc plot (from tidycmprsk::cuminc), how can I merge the 2 curves (and risk tables) together on the same plot? (and not side by side as below)
df <- data.frame(
  time1 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
  status1 = sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE),
  time2 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
  status2 = sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE))

library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggplot2)
a <- cuminc(Surv(time1, factor(status1)) ~ 1, df) %>% 
  ggcuminc() + add_risktable()
b <- cuminc(Surv(time2, factor(status2)) ~ 1, df) %>% 
  ggcuminc() + add_risktable()
library(patchwork)
wrap_plots(
  ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit_build(a),
  ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit_build(b),ncol = 2)



Instead of creating separate models and plots you could reshape your data to long then estimate one model and create one plot:
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)

df_long <- df |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "what"),
    names_pattern = c("(.*?)(\\d)")
  )

cuminc(Surv(time, factor(status)) ~ what, df_long) |> 
  ggcuminc() +
  add_risktable()
#> Plotting outcome "1".



Thanks a lot! My original dataset is a bit more complicated: in fact I only have one status and 2 delays (time1 and time2), I also have a categorial variable (treatment). So it does look more like this:
'''df <- data.frame(
time1 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
time2 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
status = sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE),
ttt= sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)).'''
I want to merge 3 cuminc curves: i) all individuals, time1, status ; ii) only ttt = 1 individuals, time1, status ; iii) only ttt = 1 individuals, time2, status. How to proceed?
